# SVG background color doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: css, svg, firefox, background, background-color

I have svg icon, looking like add to watchlist but background color doesn't work on the firefox browser, any help will be appreciated.

```css
      svg {
        background-color: #1ebaed;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
      }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
  <defs>
    <image width="40" height="40" id="watchlist" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAMAAAC7IEhfAAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAYBQTFRFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADw8PJSUlNDQ0Ojo6Ozs7Nzc3LS0tGRkZFxcXUFBQp6en5OTk+Pj4/////Pz88PDwxsbGdHR0Kysrf39/6+vr+/v7tLS0W1tb6enpyMjIe3t7R0dHPT09X19fq6ur7u7unp6eFhYWCgoK7OzsV1dXIiIiurq63t7eNjY2EBAQvb298/PzNTU1Li4uDg4OBQUFtra2SUlJBwcHvLy8fX19ERERrKys/f393NzcHh4e9PT09vb2AQEBkJCQEhISBAQEra2t8vLyISEhpqamOTk50tLSJCQkhoaGZGRkpaWlTExMzc3NlpaWxMTECAgIwsLC4uLiDAwM1dXVQUFBiYmJODg45+fn/v7+Tk5O4eHhjIyMCQkJdXV119fXYmJic3NzMjIyeHh4iIiI2dnZv7+/AgICbm5ueXl5ExMTqampdnZ2Ly8vGxsbGBgYTU1NRkZGSkpKysrK9/f35eXlQkJCx8fHcXFxn5+fpKSkk5OTQ0NDFRUVnB3CTAAAAIB0Uk5T3O3y//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////9MrCj1AAABXUlEQVR4nGNgYCQKMDAwMRMFmBgYiVPIOKqQRgpZWNnYOTi5uPEr5OHl4xcQBAIhYRFRMZwKucUlBJGApBQ7doXSMmB5WTl5BUUlZTBbRRVToZoKWEpdA8LV1AJztXXQFerqgSX0DYBsVkMjZmZjE4iAKapCM3OIuyyYmS2tBKxt5JmZbe3AIvYKyAodHCHq1J2YnV1ADFc3ZmZ3iBi/KpJCD6hHPR2YvazBLG9mZh+ooC+SQj+omD8zsxiEFQAMBahgIJLCoGCIWEgQc2gYmBXOzBwBDc5IZM+4RYEFo2OYmdligZJxzMzxsRCFCajBwwYJ7URgwDglJacARVIh6tLQA5wrHSyeYQvhZmZB7M3GjMKcXLCURF5+QaFXEcTRicVYE0VJKVjW2lW4DMwo9w7FmiiAoMJFWwgaKBKVVU5IMhgJN95QMaK6praqrh5VfFBlrpGhkOjCntjqAwB2bUIilx2T4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
  </defs>
  <style>
    tspan { white-space:pre }
  </style>
  <g id="Mobile View Expanded">
    <use id="Watchlist icon" style="mix-blend-mode: lighten" href="#watchlist" x="0" y="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The use element hides the background. Remove it and you'll see that Firefox does display the background colour.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, but why, for example, on the Chrome browser color is applied to the use element and not on the Firefox.

Comment: Something to do with how the png file is displayed i.e. not an SVG issue.